# Coupled system of linear parabolic PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Hi,

Are there any existence results for the coupled system of linear parabolic PDEs:
$$u_t - a_1u_{xx} - a_2u_x - a_3u = f_1$$
$$v_t - a_3u_{xx} - a_4u_x - a_5u - a_6v_{xx} - a_7v_x - a_8v = f_2$$
where the $a_i(x,t)$ are functions with nice properties (eg. continuous). I'm looking for solutions in parabolic Holder space preferably.

I tried Ladyzenskaja but they don't seem to be able to handle this kind of system.

Thank you.

Comment: Can I not solve for $u$ first, then solve for $v$?

Comment: Your question makes this sound like homework.

Comment: @Deane it's definitely not homework.

Comment: I am interested in this as I want to apply an inverse function theorem argument for existence of a nonlinear system.

Comment: I don't think you'll get good results if the $a_i$ are merely continuous, since in that case there may not be a good maximal regularity theory. But if all coefficients and the $f_i$ are in $C^{\alpha,\alpha/2}$ in the sense of Ladyzhenskaya, then the mapping $M: f_1 \mapsto a_3u_{xx} + a_4 u_x + a_5 u$ is linear and bounded and therefore you are just solving a linear equation for $v$.    